# CMake - Check if a directory contains a file of a specific type

Tags: cmake

I want to do a Macro that gets a list of the sub-sub-directories that contain a specific type of files, in my case **.jar** files.

This macro is getting me all the sub-sub-directories:

```
MACRO(SUBSUBDIRLIST result curdir)
  FILE(GLOB children RELATIVE ${curdir} ${curdir}/*/*)
  SET(dirlist "")
  FOREACH(child ${children})
    IF(IS_DIRECTORY ${curdir}/${child})
      LIST(APPEND dirlist ${child})
    ENDIF()
  ENDFOREACH()
  SET(${result} ${dirlist})
ENDMACRO()

SUBSUBDIRLIST(TUTORIALS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

What I now need is to find a way to check if a directory contains any **.jar** file.

Can I change the **IF** to do something like `IF(child ${children} AND ${child} CONTAINS *.jar)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `if` command supports many ready-made checks, not all checks can be expressed directly via `if`. But you are free to use other commands, and check their result via `if`.

For check whether given directory contains specific type of files, `FILE(GLOB)` can be effectively used:

```
FILE(GLOB jars "${child}/*.jar")
if(jars)
    # There are .jar files in directory referred by 'child'
endif()
```